# Почему += не работает в return и print()?

Tags: python

При следующем коде

```
class Num():
    def __init__(self, val): 
        self.val = val
        
    def __iadd__(self, other): 
        return Num(self.val + other.val)
        
        
a = Num(4)
b = Num(6)

print(a += b)
```

Наткнулся на следующую ошибку:

```
File "main.py", line 12
    print(a += b)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Если `+=` поменять на `+`, то всё корректно отрабатывает, но с `+=` почему-то падает ошибка. При этом в какой-нибудь функции `return a += b` создаст такую же проблему.

Вопрос: Почему `+=` вызывает ошибки, если `__iadd__` возвращает значение?

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778646/python-operator-and-syntaxerror

Comment: Не вижу проблемы сделать вот так: `a = 1 b = 2 a += b print(a)`

Comment: Ну всё-таки это присваивание, хотя и своеобразное. Нельзя написать `print(a = b)` и тут примерно тоже самое.

Comment: a += b
и потом:
print(a.val)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Присваивание в print сделать можно, вот так:

```py
class Num():
    def __init__(self, val): 
        self.val = val

    def __add__(self, other):  # (1)
        return Num(self.val + other.val)


a = Num(4)
b = Num(6)

print(a := a + b)  # (2)
```

1. Изменить `__iadd__` на `__add__`
2. Использовать "моржовый оператор".

Answer (score 6):

Вы, наверно, программировали в Си или подобном языке.

Но **Питон не Cи (C/C++)**. B **Cи** каждое присвоение является тоже **выражением** (с точно определенным значением).

В Питоне `a += b` не имеет значение, даже не `None`. Это только команда. :-(

И хотя функция`__iadd__()` возвращает значение, оно применится только для присвоения.

---

*Примечание:*

Чтобы в Питоне было возможно одновременно использовать присвоение как выражение, с версии **Питон 3.8** возможно вместо оператора `=` применить оператор **`:=`** — тогда такое присвоение будет тоже выражением, аналогично Cи.

Но нет оператора `:+=`.
Значит, чтобы ваш пример работал, нужно заменить `a += b` выражением `a := a + b`.

Answer (score 1):

Оператор `+=` не ожидает возвращения значения из метода `__iadd__`. Он предполагает, что `__iadd__` изменит текущий объект и вернет его, но не ожидает, что возвращенное значение будет использовано как выражение.

Если нужно использовать += внутри print(), попробуй переопределить метод `__add__` вместо `__iadd__` и возвращать новый объект.